# How to call a generic method with a deconstruct array as it's parameter

Tags: typescript, generics, overriding, typescript-generics

### I need to call a generic method with a deconstruct array as parameters

as i know, of today, the only way to have, typed safe, inherit parameters, is to use a deconstructed array and forcing it's type
then to call the father method, using the apply prototype

### for example:

this GET promise request

```js
public async getAsync<T>(url: string, options: HttpOptions<'GET'>): Promise<T> {
    try {
      const response = await this.http.get(url, options.params, options.headers);
      return response.data;
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error(e);

    }
  }
```

#### Let's say i will need the **same method but as an observable**

> in my actual case, there are multiple methods with specific parameters, that would be chaotic to setup as static parameter types, since it would change as the project requirements shift.
> so i needed to use the parameter array, **if you have a better solution for this declaration, please feel free to send it**

the way i **thought** it would go:

```js
public getObservable<T>(...params: Parameters<HttpService['getAsync']>): Observable<T> {
    const request = this.getAsync<T>.apply(this,params);
    return from(request);
}
```

but it wasn't:

[image: .apply error]

**so i wonder, if there is a way to call a generic method with .apply?**

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link, this a web IDE with your code in it)](https://tsplay.dev/W4pVeW), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing (so no unrelated errors such as unimported or undeclared values or types). This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try with `bind` method:

```
    public getObservable<T>(...params: Parameters<HttpService['getAsync']>): Observable<T> {
        const request = this.getAsync.bind(this);
        return from(request<T>(...params));
    }
```